# Flask: Converting large query result to JSON: exceeded memory limit

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a **flask** rest server with a lot of methods for retrieving json, tsv and csv files.

Using **SQLAlchemy** to execute raw sql queries.

---

I'm now working on a treemap.

---

Example query result:

```
date - group - person - value
1,1 - Alpha - John Test - 7
1,1 - Alpha - William Test - 7
```

---

Needed json format:

```
[{
  "date": "1,1",
  "name" :"Fixed",
  "children":[{
  "name" :"Alpha",
  "children":[{
    "name":"John Test",
    "size":"7"
  },
  {
    "name":"William Test",
    "size":"7"
  }
]
  },
  {
"name":"Beta",
"children" :[{
  "name":"Another Test",
  "size":"10"
}
```

---

**My approach**

**res** will be the database result rest

```
base = {
    "date": "",
    "name": "Frentes",
    "children": []
}
child = {
    "name": "",
    "children": []
}
sub_child = {
    "name": "",
    "size": ""
}
c = 'children'
for row in res:
    for k, v in list(row.items()):
        if k == 'date':
            if len(ret) == 0 or ret[-1]['date'] != v:
                ret.append(base.copy())
                ret[-1]['date'] = v
                continue
            else:
                continue
        elif k == 'group':
            if len(ret[-1][c]) == 0 or ret[-1][c][-1]['name'] != v:
                ret[-1][c].append(child.copy())
                ret[-1][c][-1]['name'] = v
                continue
            else:
                continue
        elif k == 'person':
            if len(ret[-1][c][-1][c]) == 0 or ret[-1][c][-1][c][-1]['name'] != v:
                ret[-1][c][-1][c].append(sub_child.copy())
                ret[-1][c][-1][c][-1]['name'] = v
                continue
            else:
                continue
        elif k == 'value':
            ret[-1][c][-1][c][-1]['size'] = v
            break
```

---

When i execute the code with all the real results on a full database:

i can print **ret**

I get memory error if i try json.dumps(ret)

I tried diferrent ways with json.dumps and jsonify but couldn't make it work.

I had in mind streaming everything to a file and return that file, but im not sure.

Any thoughts?

Important note: I have a cache for the returned json / tsv / csv files with a configurable duration.

Comment: You have quadratic behavior. When you do `base.copy()`, you're not copying `children`, so that single list you defined for `base` gets appended to over and over and over again, so wherever `children` appears in the object graph, it contains **all** of the children you've ever had. This blows up your memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll check it and see how to solve it.